# How to read tomcat SSL certificate expiration date

Tags: shell, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I am trying to read tomcat SSL/TLS certificate using Python shell and `openssl` but getting below error:

```
openssl x509 -in /opt/conf/.keystore -noout -dates
unable to load certificate
139716531042120:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

My SSL certificate type is `ppk7`. I have searched many posts but could not find answer.

If anyone can give me solution in python that is also fine.

Comment: I believe you need to use keytool (which comes with java) to interact with the keystore. It might ask for a password to access it and if I'm not mistaken the default one is "changeit".

Comment: yes, password can be read from server.xml. But I need to do it in python, is there anything similar to java? Please help me

Comment: Your question said Python or shell. You could call system commands from Python or you could try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjks/0.3.0.1 . Never used though, I can't help you there.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution (don't know if this is correct or not). I have read `server.xml` in conf folder of tomcat and get https port as shown below

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
 URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
 ........
 ........ 
 port="9443"  <!--https port-->
 scheme="https" 
 secure="true" 
 sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

used below shell command to read SSL certificate infor and save it in a file.

```
openssl s_client -connect MACHINE_HOST_NAME:SSL_PORT_NUMBER > /tmp/FILE_NAME.crt
```

then decode this file to read expiration date as below

```
openssl x509 -in /tmp/FILE_NAME.crt -noout -enddate
```

this produces output like below

```
notAfter=Aug 31 23:59:59 2019 GMT
```

similary you can read start date, issuer, serial number etc.